# Discordpy, Praw, get img preview of a link or if there isn't a link and there's an img attached, embed that one

Tags: discord, discord.py, reddit, praw

I'm using discordpy and the Praw module to access Reddit. I was wondering how I send the image preview of an article that is attached to the reddit submission, or, if there is no reddit link and there's instead an image attached, how I send that.

This is my current code:

```
@client.command()
@cooldown(1, 5, BucketType.user) #Command can only be used once every 5 seconds
async def webdev(ctx):
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit("webdev") #Subreddit name 
    all_subs = []

    hot = subreddit.hot(limit = 100)

    for submission in hot: #Iterating through the submissions in hot
        all_subs.append(submission) #Appending the submissions to the all_subs variable list

    random_sub = random.choice(all_subs) #Using the random module to randomly select one

    name = random_sub.title #Title of the submission
    body = random_sub.selftext #Body text of the submission
    link = random_sub.shortlink #Link to the submission
    url = random_sub.url #image of the submission
    img = random_sub.thumbnail #thumbnail of an exterior link (if there is one)

    em = discord.Embed(title = name) #Creating discordpy embed
    em.description = body #Setting the descriptiong to the body variable
    em.set_image(url = url) or em.set_image(url = img) #Attempting to send either the image attachment, or a link preview image
    em.add_field(name = f"Link to post:", value = link, inline= False) #Adding the submission link
    


    await ctx.send(embed = em) #Sending the embed
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to send the image, it got to be hosted somewhere. With your Discord bot, you can either send an image from a link or an image that is locally hosted with your bot.

You can send the image with the link like you did with your code. Otherwise, you will have to save the image on your host then send it from there.

To save your image on your host, you can use PIL module. Convert the image that you get into a savable file, then use `img.save("name.png")` then you can use: `file = discord.File("name.png")` to get the image then use it with `set_image()` after that, you just have to send the embed this way: `await ctx.send(embed = em, file = file)`